# how can I connect program to database in another pc?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-string

I'm making a program with c# , 
and after finishing it I'll setup the program in more than one pc ,
I want to connect the program in all PCs to one database in another pc using sql server .
how can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

Configure the connection string in your program to point at the database server.

An example from http://www.connectionstrings.com:

> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User
>   Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: you'll want to make sure tcp/ip is enabled on the sql server machine and remote connections are allowed.  i believe tcp/ip is disabled by default.  enabling is easiest through the sql server configuration manager.

Answer (score 1):

One example would be setting up an MySQL-Database at on of you PCs. You can get it from the [MySQL Website](http://www.mysql.de/downloads/mysql/5.5.html). After that you need to connect to it in any way. To connect to that database you may use the [.NET Connector](http://www.mysql.de/downloads/connector/net/). Using it you can access a remote databasein a fashion like this:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...

string myConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                            "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
                            "UID=user;" +
                            "PASSWORD=mypassword;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    string row = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
        row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
connection.Close();
...
```

In a similiar way you may

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server, not MySQL.